# frequency ts end forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have data per hour for 3 weeks. I want to make a forecast for a week, I use the ts of R for my analysis and to forecast. What should be the frequency parameter for the ts and for the forecast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frequency` parameter tells R how many observations there are per seasonal cycle.

Your data are hourly, and your seasonal cycle is weekly. There are 168 hours in a week. So you need to set `frequency=168`.